# jquery problem: callback is fired for each selector (ie 3 selectors, fired three times)

Tags: jquery

**This fires the callback twice:**

```
$('#get_started, #favour').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('#wrap_right').data('first_click_made', true);
    setup_tab_1(id);
    load_fb_js();               
});
```

**this doesn't but is it the best way to fix the problem?**

```
$('#wrap_right #favour').fadeOut(300);
$('#get_started').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('#wrap_right').data('first_click_made', true);
    setup_tab_1(id);
    load_fb_js();               
});
```

Comment: What's the problem? What are you expecting to achieve with the above code?

Comment: There's no point in putting both '#wrap_right' and '#favour' in that selector. Just use '#favor' - the "id" value has to be unique anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative:

```
$('#get_started, #favour').fadeOut(300, function(){
    if (this.id === 'get_started')
    {
        $('#wrap_right').data('first_click_made', true);
        setup_tab_1(id);
        load_fb_js();               
    }
});
```